# Javascript Array Bug - by changing one all other arrays get changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

I was doing Codeforces problem when I encountered a bug I don't actually know how to fix:

Problem:

> Vasya has invented a new hash function of an array. It is calculated as follows. While the array has at least two elements, the first two elements, call them 1 and 2, are deleted, and the new element 2−1 is inserted to the beginning of the array. When the array has only one element, this number is a value of Vasya's hash function of this array.
>
> Vasya has the array 1
>   , 2,..., . He performs  operations of the following form: "increase all elements in the segment [,] by ". After each operation he wants to know the value of Vasya's hash function of this array.
>
> Input: The first line contains an integer (1≤≤500000) — the size of the array.
>   The second line contains  integers  (−109≤≤109) — the elements of the array.
>   The third line contains an integer  (1≤≤200000) — the number of operations.
>   Each of the next  lines contains three integers , ,  (1≤≤≤, −109≤≤109) — the parameters of the -th operation.
>
> Output: Output  lines. In the -th line output one integer — the value of Vasya's hash function after the -th operation.

When I change an array (both inside and outside the while loop) automatically all the other array get changed too.

I  don't really know what to try and how to fix it.

```
function hash(n, inputArray, q, operations){

    let result = [];

    for (const operation of operations) {   
        let new_array = array_operation(inputArray, operation[0], operation[1], operation[2]);

        while (new_array.length >= 2) {
            let new_value = new_array.shift() + new_array.shift();
            new_array.unshift(new_value);
        }

        result.push(new_array.shift());
    }
    return result;
}

function array_operation(array, start, end, value){
    for (const i in array) if (i >= --start && i < end) array[i] += value;
    return array;
}

console.log(hash(7, [4, 2, -5, 10, 4, -2, 6], 2, [[2, 4, -8,], [5, 7, 2], [3, 3, -1], [3, 7, 3]]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clone the `new_array` rather than using the same array to run operations as `shift` mutates the original array.

```
function array_operation(array, start, end, value) {
    let cloned_array = [...array];   

    for (const i in cloned_array) {
        if (i >= --start && i < end) {
           cloned_array[i] += value;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: `inputArray ` is the only one that gets updated right and you want to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can fix.

```
function array_operation(array, start, end, value){
    for (const i in array) if (i >= --start && i < end) array[i] += value;
    return [...array];
}
```